# Help me translate the Chinese in the login

Tags: translation

I need the stranslation of this text in the image.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What trouble were you having? What did Google Translate tell you, and what remains unclear? Please edit your question to add some more details so we know exactly what you’ve tried and why that didn’t answer the question for you.

Comment: Sorry, but removing the text that says what you tried to do won’t make it any better – you’re _supposed_ to give information about what you tried to do, otherwise the question is considered off-topic by default. StackExchange is not a translation service, but a place to ask well-thought-out questions and receive (hopefully) authoritative answers to them. It would be much better if you could clarify your own initial research and how far that got you; then we can help you get further.

Comment: @Janus Apparently this community doesn't care. Throw anything here, just wait, you'll an answer.Unlike other "unfriendly" community, no questions will be closed

Answer (score 3):

It's something like this after translation. Hope this helped

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the first textbox, it requires your phone number, the second one would be a code given in a short message after you click the button beside the second textbox. The third and the forth textbox requires you to set your password( one to set , another to confirm). After that you can click the “下一步” button and enjoy.